# How to display dropdown in UITableViewController Static Cell iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to display a dropdown like NIDropDown in a static cell. How can I do that. If I display dropdown on cell it's not showing properly due to cell height and I don't want to change height. Is there any idea or third party lib?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS there is no DropDown control as such but you can either customize the the UIControl to show the drop down or use third party pods to show the same. Here are few examples. Hope this will help you. Good-Luck.
[example1](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) [example-2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=dropdown)